# How to use JPQL without @Query annotation inside the method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpql

I want to use dependency inversion principle inside my book rental project. Before, I used `AccountRepository` that extends `CrudRepository`, so my method looked like this:

```
@Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(account) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END FROM 
Account account WHERE account.id =:accountID")
boolean doesAccountExistsWithGivenID(@Param("accountID") int accountID);
```

I've created `AccountRepository` and class that implements this repository. 
Class that implements interface is called `PostgreSQLAccountRepository`. And inside `doesAccountExistsWithGivenID` I want to query somehow to get same result.
It looks like this:

```
package bookrental.account;

import bookrental.bookrentals.BookRentals;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class PostgreSQLAccountRepository implements AccountRepository {

    private CrudRepository<Account, Integer> repository;

    public PostgreSQLAccountRepository(CrudRepository<Account, Integer> repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<BookRentals> getAccountRentalsByGivenID(int accountID) {
       //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Integer id) {
       this.repository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Account> findAll() {
        return (List<Account>) this.repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean doesAccountExistsWithGivenID(int accountID) {
        //HERE I WANT TO USE JPQL
    }
``}
```

I do not want to use `existsByID`, because I have a lot of methods that use JPQL so I need to know how to implement it inside the method.

Comment: To enforce dependency inversion you could also use 2 classes. One which extends your CrudRepository where you can use JPQL. The other implements your interface and delegates all requests to the specific functions of the repository. This means a bit more boilerplate code but would ultimately solve your problem.

Comment: @SlideM you mean: repository(extends crudrepository) -> class having methods like repository.findAll() - > particular class, right?

Comment: That's the core idea. You could even go a step further to true clean architecture if you really want to and have your own database entities separated from your core classes. That requires class mapping but would allow your core business logic to be completely separate from changes in your database module. If you want to learn more: http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is clear on how to customize methods from a Data repository:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Basically define the fragment of the interface you want to customize (`CustomizedRepository`). Extend this interface in your data repository

```
interface SomeRepositry extends CrudRepository<...>, CustomizedRepository
```

Create implementation for `CustomizedRepository` called `CustomiyedRepositoryImpl`. The `Impl` postfix is critical here. See the docs for more customizations.

Comment: I do not want to extends CrudRepository.

Comment: It begs the question why? Are you trying to tie the Service and Repo into one class?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to autowire the `SessionFactory` and use it manually.

```
  @Autowired
  public setSessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
    if(factory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class) == null){
      throw new NullPointerException("factory is not a hibernate factory");
    }
    this.hibernateFactory = factory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
  }
```

After you have access to it, then you can use it directly

```
Session session = hibernateFactory.createSession();
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(account) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END FROM  Account account WHERE account.id =:accountID");
query.setParameter("accountId", "7277");
List list = query.list();
```